# Conditional String Separators in SSRS using VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a function in SSRS using VB.NET as follows:

```
Public Function GenerateCSV(byval str as string, byval str1 as string, byval str2 as string, byval GrpName as string) 
  IF GroupName <> GrpName THEN
    GroupName = GrpName
    CSVString = ""
  END IF
  IF str = ""
    CSVString = ""
  ELSE
    CSVString = CSVString & str & ", " & str1 & ", " & str2 & ", " 
  END IF
  return CSVString
End function
```

This works great is str, str1 and str2 have a value and only one value. But I want to make it so if the value isn't there or there is only one value there is no comma and if there are multiple commas there is a comma. Is there an easy way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. Create array from your non-empty arguments.
2. Use `String.Join` method to concatenate array elements.

Example: 
    String.Join("," values)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.join